# Moving fireplace mantle mounted with bolts in mortar and liquid nails

Tags: concrete, walls, wood, fireplace

i’d like to attempt to have our fireplace mantle moved just a little bit lower as we don’t use the fireplace, but want to change the function of the mantle a bit.

it looks like it’s mounted with two bolts drilled into the mortar, with what I can only assume is liquid nails adhering the wood to the bolts. i’ve included a photo of one of the said bolts for reference.

how big of a pain would it be to remove this and then reinstall? is it even possible without damaging the mantle?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If the mantle is really on the bolts by some kind of serious adhesive, your best best to not damage the mantle and wall is to cut the bolts if they are visible (sawzall, oscillating tool  hack saw, etc.). Once off the wall, you can flush up the cut on both sides, and reinstall in the new location using the same technique.

If the bolts aren't visible, but you know where they are, you can still cut them if you accept a little damage / clean up to the back edge of the mantle and/or brick face. You'll have to judge the risk you're willing to take with your repair skills.

Comment: In case it isn't that serious an adhesive, I'd try pulling/prying first to see if I could get the board off the supports. But there's nonzero odds you're going to have to sawzall/grind the bolts even if that succeeded.